# Can I get DocumentSnapshot.data(as:) to use field default values?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching a document from Firestore, and I'm marshalling it into a struct using the `DocumentSnapshot.data(as:)` function from `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`. I want to be able to set default values for certain fields that may or may not exist on the document (like `privateProfile` below).

However, when the prop doesn't exist on the document, an error is thrown from `DocumentSnapshot.data(as:)`. Is there a way to get the below example to work or do I have to get creative (e.g. custom decoder initialiser)?

```
struct MyUser: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username: String?
    var privateProfile: Bool = true // This is what's causing the issue.
    // var privateProfile: Bool?    // Would work, but then I have to handle nil values everywhere.
}

userDataListener = db.collection(usersCollection).document(userID)
    .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            do {
                if let u = try querySnapshot.data(as: MyUser.self) {
                    self.user = u
                }
            } catch {
                // Handle error...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `CodingKeys`

Comment: How does that help with the default values for missing properties?

Comment: Via `CodingKeys` you can specify the properties that you want to decode.  If you don't have `privateProfile` in the `CodingKeys` enum then the decoder won't attempt to decode it (I am assuming that Firebase is using `Codable` under the covers).

Comment: Ahh ok, that's not my issue. My issue is that some documents have the `privateProfile` key and some don't. If a value is present, I want it unmarshalled into the field, if it's absent I want to treat it as if it was set to true i.e. true by default. (Yes, it's using Codable,  and what you're saying is correct)

Comment: Ok.  That wasn't clear from your question.  You will need to implement your own decoding code by implementing `init(from decoder: Decoder)`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :( But thanks for your help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224007/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mathias-bak).

Answer (score 1):

With help from [@Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) we figured that the nicest way while keeping the default values in the field declarations would be writing a custom initialiser like so

```
struct MyUser: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username: String?
    var privateProfile: Bool = true

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id             = "id"
        case username       = "username"
        case privateProfile = "private_profile"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let c = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try c.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.username = try c.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .username)
        self.privateProfile = try c.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .privateProfile) ?? self.privateProfile
    }
}
```

It's a lot to write when there are many fields though.